# Adding to field audit of a custom object

Tags: apex, trigger, field-history

I am trying to add records to the field audit of a custom object using apex trigger ? Should I use the fieldHistoryarchive object or the (customobject)history object? Can anyone provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant insert record into any of these objects .You can only query them and cannot make a fresh entry into this table .

The audit is internally populated by salesforce .

Comment: Can I not write some apex code to insert into these objects?

Comment: No you cannot ..Its only salesforce that can write this .